# Xaml Behavior DP not updated

Tags: xaml, uwp, behavior

I have a UWP application which uses the Managed UWP Behavior SDK.
I wrote a custom behavior which has two dependency properties, one of which is a ObservableCollection.

Whenever I update an item in the collection, I make sure that PropertyChanged is called for the collection.

However, the Dependency property is not being updated.

My code:

```
<trigger:CustomBehavior ItemIndex="{x:Bind ItemIndex}"
     Presences="{Binding ElementName=Box,
         Path=DataContext.CustomCollection,
             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}}" />
```

My TestConverter shows me that when I update an item in the collection, the updatesource trigger is working. The dependency property in my behavior however, is not firing the Changed event. When I change the entire custom collection, the DP is updated, when I just change one item, it isn't.

Research so far says that DependencyObject.SetValue just checks to see if the object has changed and if one item changed, it will just think that the collection didn't change at all? Is this true, and if so, how can I overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: A note first: "when I update an item in the collection, the updatesource trigger is working" is a common misunderstanding. Setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on a one-way binding has no effect, it only controls how the source of a binding is updated when the target changes, i.e. is only effective in two-way or one-way-to-source bindings. That said, updating an item in a collection and then raising a PropertyChanged event also has no effect, since the collection *instance* hasn't changed and the PropertyChanged event is silently ignored.

Comment: Either you replace the entire collection, or you register a handler for the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event in the PropertyChangedCallback of the Presences property.

Comment: Beautiful. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A collection-type dependency property should usually be declared as the most basic collection type, `IEnumerable`. This way you can assign a variety of actual collection types to the property, including those that implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, like `ObservableCollection<T>`.

You would check at runtime if the collection type actually implements the interface, and possibly attach and detach a handler method for the `CollectionChanged` event.

```cs
public class CustomBehavior : ...
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PresencesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Presences", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(CustomBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(null,
                (o, e) => ((CustomBehavior)o).OnPresencesPropertyChanged(e)));

    private void OnPresencesPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var oldCollectionChanged = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        var newCollectionChanged = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

        if (oldCollectionChanged != null)
        {
            oldCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= OnPresencesCollectionChanged;
        }

        if (newCollectionChanged != null)
        {
            newCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += OnPresencesCollectionChanged;
            // in addition to adding a CollectionChanged handler, any
            // already existing collection elements should be processed here
        }
    }

    private void OnPresencesCollectionChanged(
        object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // handle collection changes here
    }
}
```